# Redirect to subdirectory html form

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, directory

I'm having an issue getting a form to perform the action I need it to.
The form is this

```
<form action="./" method="get" class=""><div class="group">
  <input name="./" id="" type="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" id="submit">
  <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span><label>Enter Username</label></div>
  <button type="submit" class="button buttonBlue">Enter
  <div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div></button>
</form>
```

I want users to enter a subdirectory name and be directed to that particular subdirectory.

For example, domain.com --> domain.com/subdirectory
If possible show them an error if subdirectory not available.
Any help will be appreciate it!

Comment: *"Any help will be appreciate it!"* - Yes and we know you would. *But*, as is something you may have tried would be a "ditto" ;-)

Comment: Here's something to help you out; `name="./"` that would be invalid as an input name.

Comment: I copied the form and it came with some fields, then I tried to edit so I guess I need to reconsider the whole thing.

Comment: what you can do is assign it a proper alpha-numerical name and then use a function that will allow for folder access, and then just make it go down a sub-folder or 2; that's doable.

Comment: The form is the least of the issue what it the PHP that it calls? You have an action of `./` which might call this script again. You might want that or something like `action="findpath.php"` which does the redirect for you. Also, as other mentioned `name="./"` is not right do something like `name="user_path"` and an empty `id` and `type` is just clutter...